# HOW TO Revert Action Bar after Switching Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

### **Problem:**

The **`Fragment`** backstack is made so that traversing backwards through a stack of fragments in one activity does not revert the Action Bar to its original state in the previous fragment.

### Why does this happen?

Turns out, the Action Bar is actually attached to the Activity itself, not the fragment! Remember, fragments are only modular bits of the **UI**, and have to explicitly specify control to other fragments, sections of the activity, or even the Action Bar.

*Keep reading for the solution...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

I found that the best approach to this problem is done by what is generally described in Reto Meier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751068/1748607) to a previous question. My solution will just expand more deeply on his answer.

What we want to establish though is that we don't want to re-create the action bar every time we switch to a different fragment, reason being it's not very efficient. I'm going to walk you through an I wrote for a student scheduling app. It's not very complicated, and it's onboarding experience is composed of multiple fragments held within an activity.

To make this work, we need to make sure we're using **`replace()`** to switch between fragments. This is better than layering fragments on top of each other, because it lets you configure the action bar separately for each fragment.

The first chunk of code comes from the activity's inner class, **`LoginOptionsFragment`**, in its **`onCreateView()`** method.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_options, container, false);
        //LoginOptionsFragment will have its own action bar
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //inject views. e.g: Button add_course
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        add_course.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        //exchange fragments. no messy clean-up necessary.
                        .replace(R.id.container, new AddCourseFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here, I not only make sure to call **`onCreateOptionsMenu()`** via the **`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`**, but mainly, as soon as the "ADD COURSE" button is clicked to switch to the **`AddCourseFragment`**, the new fragment replaces the old fragment as the primary child of the activity. Next, after we override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, we come to `onResume()`, but we'll get to that later ;)

Secondly, we arrive at the `AddCourseFragment`, where we even inflate a custom **done-cancel view** for the action bar. So let's look at the code!

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (inflate_set_custom_view)
        // Inflate a "Done/Cancel" custom action bar view.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) actionBar.getThemedContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflate custom action bar view
        View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_cancel, null);

        //set listeners to items in the view
        customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_done).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // "Done"
                        //remove custom view from action bar
                        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        //add course to list
                    }
                });
        customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_cancel).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // "Cancel"
                        //remove custom view from action bar
                        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }
                });

        // Show the custom action bar view and hide the normal Home icon and title.
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
                ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
                ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView,
                new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        // END_INCLUDE (inflate_set_custom_view)

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_course, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        return rootView;
    }
```

The **ONLY** part that you need to pay attention to are the **`OnClickListener`**'s added to the **DONE** and **CANCEL** buttons. In here, I use my previous reference to the parent `Activity`'s action bar and tell it to stop displaying the custom view. Now in addition to this specific method, there are more `setDisplayXEnabled()` methods that you can pass in false to. After that, I pop the backstack to get to the previous fragment.

### But how do I actually revert the action bar!?

Here's how. Remember that **`onResume()`** method that was hanging out in our `LoginOptionsFragment`? Well, `onResume()` is called once a fragment gets back into focus from the backstack! So if we override it and **re-enable** the parts of the action bar that we want, we win right? Yes we do. Here is all you need to add into the `onResume()`.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); //show Home icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show title
//      actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true); <--- more options
//      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); <--- more options
    }
```

And we did it all without recreating the action bar. Here's how it looks!

[image: output]

Thanks for reading, and happy coding!