# How to refresh a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a PhotosFragment class which extends Fragment. In that class I have a gridview of images. When I delete image it will delete successfully, but the fragment couldn't refresh. So how to refresh the fragment ?

```
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                imageId = imageArry.get(position).getID();
                deletePhoto(imageId);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

// method to deletePhoto

```
   protected void deletePhoto(int id) {

    final int t_id = id;
     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     alert.setTitle("Delete");
     alert.setMessage("Do you want to delete this image ?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                db.deleteContact(new Contact(t_id));
                //HERE I want to REFRESH THE FRAGMENT
                }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert.show();

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you deleting the image?

Comment: remove from view and add the same second time.

Comment: you have to detach your fragment first .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload

Comment: using 'gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener' I delete the image

Comment: 'Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();'

Comment: Can you post your `setOnItemLongClickListener()` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` method from the adapter of the `GridView` to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate your layout View

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id).invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should refresh all fragment. You can either do something like this `imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or, better, remove item from your gridView's adapter:

```
adapter.remove(object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For more, I suggest refer to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)