# How to reload a Viewpager's Fragment from an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity in which layout has Tabs using TabLayout and viewpager from fragments. There are two tabs and having 2 fragments 1 for each tab.
Now I am on second Tab's Fragment, when I perform any action in this fragment, I have to reload that fragment, but when I am restarting that activity using the below code:

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();
mContext.startActivity(((Activity) mContext).getIntent());
```

It reloads the first fragment, I want to reload the second fragment, how can I achieve this.

Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: what about `setCurrentItem(i);`

Comment: or notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You should Pass SetSelecteditem(2) on viewPager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload

Comment: So you want to go back to the same screen from where you left. You can save that info in a sharedPreference and again when you load the activity obtain the value from sharedPreference and setCurrentItem(0...(n-1)), where n is the number of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your current Fragment:

// Reload current fragment

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```