# Completely Refresh Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and I need to completely refresh/reinstantiate it. 
By refreshing I mean recreating fragment. 
I have tried using `FragmentManager` with `detach()` method but it didn't help. All `EditText` children of that fragment still have their values entered even though the fragment was refreshed

Is there any way to achieve this result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh fragment at reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload)

Answer (score 0):

if there are only edit texts , create a method that sets all edit texts to empty string that is  et(edit_text object),

```
et.setText("");    //edit text will be reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code inside the fragment which need to be refreshed.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Use fragment manger according to your code (if it is an old version then this will be supportFragmentManager)

Answer (score 0):

Put and call this method to your fragment

```
private void reloadFragment(){
    Fragment frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ReceiptFragment.TAG);
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
}
```