# Refresh The fragment on download complete in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-download-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to refresh or restart the fragment when the download completes (Download Manager) but the code must be inside Fragment class.

I used Broadcast Receiver to restart the fragment on download complete. But the code doesnt work. 
**MyFragment.java**

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .detach(getTargetFragment())
               .attach(getTargetFragment()).commit();
        }
    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a Async Task to download. Then check below link on how to refresh or restart the fragment.
[refresh fragment at reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload)