# Refresh fragment in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

How can I refresh my fragment (chart-fragment) in parent fragment?
I tried doing it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload), but it doesn't work.

Java (refresh method):

```
Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statistic_order_fragment);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/statistic_order_fragment"
                android:tag="ORDER"
                android:name="com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement.Statistic.StatisticOrderFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                card_view:layout="@layout/fragment_statistic_order" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/statistic_sum_fragment"
                android:tag="SUM"
                android:name="com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement.Statistic.StatisticSumFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                card_view:layout="@layout/fragment_statistic_sum" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/statistic_check_fragment"
                android:tag="CHECK"
                android:name="com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement.Statistic.StatisticCheckFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                card_view:layout="@layout/fragment_statistic_check" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When I use SwipeRefreshLayout, I need to refresh all the 3 Fragments without restarting the parent Fragment.

Comment: Have you tried to get the fragment by it's tag instead? getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_tag");

Comment: @RicardoBarroca Yes, the same result as with the id. Just I do with id becouse I thing this more practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you have statically placed the fragments inside your xml file. A better approach is to put `<FrameLayout>`s instead of the `<fragment>` tags in your xml. Then, in your class, add the fragments programmatically, replacing them as needed.

Let me know if you need me to show you the code to do this.

Answer (score 4):

After so much coding...
I got solution for that..

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(**containerId**,
                    new **NameOfCurrentFragment**).commit();
```

Comment: In case you want to grab the id of the current fragment, you just have to call:

`this.getId()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Child Fragment Manager is precisely made to manage fragments inside of fragments, while Fragment Manger is there to manage fragments inside of Activities.

Replace,

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

With this,

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Struggled with this since morning. Figured this out later.

Answer (score 1):

to refresh fragment call below method

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

  // Refresh tab data:

  if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
    getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .detach(this)
      .attach(this)
      .commit();
  }
}
```