# Fragment is null whenever trying to reload fragment after a delete

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list in a table fragment with delete button in each row.Whenever I tap to delete I am getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

I have used [this code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702418/2636829) to reload the page. And I found that my fragment is null. I don't know how to resolve this issue. Also how to change it to `support.v4.app` or simply `FragmentManager`.

This is my code

```
   Fragment frg = null;           
    frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.table_fragment_container);
    Log.v("frag",""+frg);  //this is null 
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg); 
ft.commit();
```

Comment: you can call notifyDatasetChanged() on list

Comment: better if you provide your code for us to review as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding TAG

```
Fragment frg = null;
 frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tabFrag");                                                       
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

and while calling this fragment i added TAG

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.RLfragment_container, mTableViewFragment, "tabFrag");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not set "Your_Fragment_TAG" tag in `onCreateView()` of your fragment, please check. Or you can use below code for fragment reloading.

```
Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(your_fragment_container);

if (currentFragment instanceof "fragment_layout_instance") {

FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =   (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
     fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
     fragTransaction.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: getting error in this line if (currentFragment instanceof "fragment_layout_instance")

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of your fragment and replace "fragment_layout_instance" with you fragment object.

Comment: Like this ri8  TableViewFragment mTableViewFragment = new TableViewFragment();  and replaced if (currentFragment instanceof mTableViewFragment ) {} but still error