# How to Reload a Page while clicked on Button?

Tags: android, json, reload

In my Application I want to retrieve a data from the database. But the problem I am facing is that, the data is fetched from database but it is not displaying at a time when I reopen the page at that time the data is displaying. I want to reload a page when I click on Button.

[image: Layout]

Here the code is as follow :-

```
Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             new InTimeInsert().execute();
        }
    });


private class InTimeInsert extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            try {
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("at_username", uid));

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_intime,"GET", params);

                //ownerObj = json.getJSONArray("visit");
                for (int i = 0; i < ownerObj.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = ownerObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    time_fetch.add(jsonobject.getString("at_itime"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            ina.setText(""+delivery_fetch);
        }
    }



private class AllAtendence extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        try {
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("at_username", uid));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_allatendence,"GET", params);

            ownerObj = json.getJSONArray("visit");
            for (int i = 0; i < ownerObj.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = ownerObj.getJSONObject(i);

                delivery_fetch =jsonobject.getString("at_date");
                lunch=jsonobject.getString("at_litime");
                rejoin=jsonobject.getString("at_lotime");
                out=jsonobject.getString("at_otime");
                Log.d("at_line",json.toString());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        ina.setText(""+delivery_fetch);
        rejoina.setText(""+lunch);
        luncha.setText(""+rejoin);
        outa.setText(""+out);
        if(ina.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            Btngetdata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            inti.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {
            Btngetdata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(luncha.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            ltime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            luncht.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            ltime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(rejoina.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            rtime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rejoint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        else
        {
            rtime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(outa.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            otime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            outt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            otime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If your are using `Activity` you can restart that `Activity` without giving `No Animation` to it.

Comment: I am using Fragment.

Comment: Then you have  to `detach` the `Fragment` and `Reattch` to it.

Comment: Can you please explain me with some code???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh fragment at reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload)

Comment: You fetching some data ... to display in some UI ........ why you need to reload page ... can you tell me purpose ... is there another UI depend  or need to update on your data  which already have some data?

Comment: @EnamulHaque  I am fetching the Current time from the APi and when i clicked on Button it will generate and insert the current time onDB and fetching the currnet time  in the TextView

Comment: Your 'time_fetch' is like this,  ArrayList<Object> time_fetch = new ArrayList<Object>();............right? New r you sure 'delivery_fetch' is perfectly assigned data form your 'time_fetch' object?

Comment: yes... should i upadate my question and upload my whole code??

Comment: ArrayList<String> time_fetch = new ArrayList<String>(); my time_fetch is like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fetch only one data than you can use this to solve your problem..
And use log to see if there is any err on fetching data... on catch block..Good luck.

```
private class InTimeInsert extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String fetched_data = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        try {
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("at_username", uid));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_intime,"GET", params);

            //ownerObj = json.getJSONArray("visit");
            for (int i = 0; i < ownerObj.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = ownerObj.getJSONObject(i);
                this.fetched_data = jsonobject.getString("at_itime");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("fetch err", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        ina.setText(""+this.fetched_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130670/discussion-on-answer-by-enamul-haque-how-to-reload-a-page-while-clicked-on-butto).

Comment: OKEYY... now record is fetching... perfectly.. but the another problem arrives the button is not hideing...
i set visibility for it in the if condition.. so when i click the button the data is displaying but Button remains as it is

Answer (score 0):

```
//put your code in onResume methods
    @Override protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       // call here
        new InTimeInsert().execute();
    }
```

Comment: fragment also have onResume method

Comment: becasue i want to perfom this task on OnClickevent

Comment: override onResume method in fragment and call  new InTimeInsert().execute();

Comment: it will directly generating the time and i need to generate it on  onClick

Comment: @Sachin what is your problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

Add `.get();`, while calling `AsyncTask`.

Like:

`new InTimeInsert().execute().get();`

It waits for the result of `AsyncTask`.

By doing this, will execute the `AsyncTask` first and then continues with the control flow.