# Android cannot update fragment datas

Tags: android, fragment

I am currently working with **fragments**,i am try to load the data from **Database** into fragments class,once i run the application my previous data saved my class, cannot **Reload** data whenever i updated **database**,
I am also refer this [refresh fragment at reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload) **But it not work for me**,

> My code was,

```
   `Fragment fragment;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
    ft.detach(fragment);
    ft.attach(fragment);
    ft.commit();`
```

And my packages 
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
                  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`

please help me friends!!

Comment: your fragment is null..use atleast on fragment

Comment: i am also in my project i will give != null  case R.id.nav_dashboard:

                fragment = new FmDashboard();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_store:

                fragment = new FmStore();
                break;                But its holds previous data!!

Comment: The code your referred has one fragment tag like `frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");` .. you can refresh the current fragment by getting the current fragment through its TAG and then by detaching and re attaching it.

Comment: Any example to create tag

Comment: i get this friend,,java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139473/discussion-between-vijay-kumar-and-ranjit-pati).

Answer (score 0):

Try my below code once and please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

```
SomeFragment fragment = null;
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);

//no need to detach
//ft.detach(fragment);
//no need to attach
//ft.attach(fragment);

//just commit 
ft.commit();`
```

**UPDATE**

Lets initiate the fragment and give it some recognition through a TAG like

```
SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "my_fragment_tag")//now you can recognize your fragment through "my_fragment_tag" 
        .commit();
```

And now you can refresh your fragment when you need by your detach/attach way

```
// Reload current fragment
Fragment frg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment_tag");
final FragmentTransaction ft =    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if(frg != null){ // if fragment is removed from memory it will give null pointer exception
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
}
```