# Restart fragment from within the same fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tab layout with a ViewPager having 3 fragments. Data inside these fragments is populated by recyclerview. I have also implemented swipe to refresh layout in this fragment.

When I pull to refresh the 'PostTab', I want to restart/reload the fragment so as to fetch the new set of data from the server. I am not able to do so.

I know there are tons of answers around this topic but I guess this is the case of having too much information and thus after trying many different things I am not able to do it.

***MainActivity*** file contains FragmentPagerAdapter to make the fragments

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new CategoryTab();

            case 1:
                return new PostTab();

            case 2:
                return new VideoTab();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle ( int position){
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Tab1 Working";
            case 1:
                return "Tab2 Working";
            case 2:
                return "Tab3 Working";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The refresh layout is present inside the PostTab fragment

PostTab.java

```
public class PostTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_tab, container, false);


    // Get data from server

    //set recycler adapter 

    //Scroll listener to load more data

    //Load more data on scroll

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshItems();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void refreshItems(){
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.attach(this);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}

}
```

The above code loads the new data properly but then my app crashes. My guess is that this code does not fully restart the fragment by calling onCreateView method again.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder
```

If I change the code to below, then fragment goes blank (Previously loaded data also goes away).

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(this);
fragmentTransaction.attact(this);
```

How do I use remove & add? As I haven't set the tag earlier my app crashes with the whatever tag I set here.

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(this);
fragmentTransaction.add(this,"Tag");
```

Can 'replace' be helpful? As per my understanding it will replace all fragments. I just need to reload 1 out of 3 fragments.

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702418/3884753) answer but I don't know the fragment tag as I haven't set it.

Comment: instead of reloading fragment why not just invalidate current adapter data and load it again

Comment: @VivekMishra Hey, I copied the Async task to get intial data from server inside the refresh items method also and reset the scroll listener to reset the different parameters inside it affected by the paginated loading async task present inside it. Till now it seems to be working. Testing the various functions present in the class to check if anything is wrong. Thanks for comment which made me rethink the approach. Still would like to know what am I doing wrong in the above method.

Comment: create a method which will set your adapter. And in that method pass your data array or list whatever you have and your view like listview or recyclerview and call that method whenever you want to show the updated record by passing new data set to the method. Remember to invalidate previous data if any

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just need to update adapter by notify method inside refreshItems() method, like `public void refreshItems(){ youradapter.notifydatasetchanged(); }`. This might be caused when you have called another fragment and setting adapter or might be you are changing position already changed.