# Managing Action Bar titles when using fragments and the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-stack

My app has an activity which uses the FragmentManager to push and pop fragments onto the backstack. However, when the backstack has 2 fragments and the last fragment is popped, I do not how to detect this to set the title of the Action Bar appropriately. I was hoping there was some method on a fragment I could override to determine when it becomes visible, but none of those suggested e.g. uservisiblehint, onHiddenChanged, etc. are called. How can I either:

• determine when a fragment becomes visible; OR

• effectively manage action bar titles when using fragments on a backstack?

Comment: looks relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack

Comment: @vipulmittal Thanks, that will work well. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept and award you the bounty.

Comment: posted as an answer. Appreciate the effort :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `addOnBackStackChangedListener` which will get called every time back stack changes. 
Inside this function you can simply get the topmost fragment and call `onResume` for it.

For more information you can refer to following link:

[Fragments onResume from back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack)