# Issue with onBackPressed() is not refresh fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

In my Android Application, I have two Fragments in my Activity, A and B.

In “A” Fragment  I have developed one form and in that form some data is coming from a database. I have used a fragment transaction and replaced fragment “A”  with fragment “B”.

**Here is my code to replace Fragment A with FragmentB.**

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  
FragmentB reload = new FragmentB();  
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,reload);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);  
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In “B” Fragment, I am fetching data from a server and storing it in an SQLite database so we can use the latest data in the application. When I click on the back button it returns back to Fragment “A” but all the data in Fragment “A” is not refreshed based on the newly-reloaded data.

Here is my code for main activity where I override `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override    
public void onBackPressed() {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
```

I want to refresh Fragment A's data with the latest values from the database when I hit the back button from the main activity. As much I know we cannot do back-press event in fragment B. Please correct me if I am wrong and suggest me how I can solve issue.

Does anybody know how I can achieve it?

Comment: addToBackStack(null) says there is no backstack and then what is the use of popBackStack? add Fragment A code, and show how fragment A is called. Every time new instance of Fragment A is loaded in fragment manager or it is same instance?

Comment: Add code of Fragment A. As you are replacing fragments, the oncreateview() method of Fragment A will be called again, So i think if you write your fetching from database code there, you would be refreshing data automatically.

Comment: You mean to say when you are going from fragment B to A, since u used replace transaction fragment a's code is called again? and new database entries that u saved in B are not reflected in A?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan i use addtobackstack(null) still its entry is available in back-stack and popbackstack() is working but  when i come from fragment B to fragment A, data in fragment A will not refresh and also oncreatview is not calling.  i want to go From fragment A to fragment B thats why i use .replace and In fragment B when i pressed back its return back to fragment A but fragment A is not refreshing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When back pressed your Fragment `onResume` will be called so you can write refresh code in onResume

for better understanding refer below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: if you are replacing fragments, even onCreateView() callback will be called.

Comment: i already try this and onResume isnot call when i come back from Fragment B.

Comment: @dora   yes i replace fragment but onCreateview() isnot callback when i return back from Fragment B.

Comment: on resume will also be called when you minimize the app and start again

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I know what the onResume for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add to back stack then you should use `fragmentTransaction.add()` . `replace` will just replace the fragment.

Also the right place to handle pop from backstack is through the use of `OnBackStackChangedListener` like this

```
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
       new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // find your fragment and do updates
           }
    });
```

A good reference [Fragments onResume from back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack)

Comment: above link is working for me and onResume() is call but its give me error NullPointerException.I use simple RelativeLayout/LinerLayout in xml file and fragment is used in all java file. May be error is raised due to simple layout. do you have any another suggestion?

Comment: That's different problem so you need to start a new post