# Manage Title with Fragment Stack Changed

Tags: android, fragment

I am using Fragment activity and a number of fragments to get added and poped out on back press.

Supposed I am adding Fragment B from Fragment A. The title of action bar that I set in A changes by navigating to B; but it is not restoring to A when I pop the fragment B out of the fragment stack as onResume of fragment is not being called.

I am using the code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentToReplace, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

and to pop out the last fragment:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

How to manage this. Please suggest.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack

Comment: in onCreateView() set title as you want in fragment.

Comment: oncreate view is not being called again as fragment is already added. I have not replaced the fragment but added the new one

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `onBackStackChanged` listener which will be called whenever a fragment is popped back. To add the listener use this:

```
 getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```

In Override function, check the fragment which is popped and according to it you can change the actionbar title:

```
  @Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
  //Check the fragment from the FrameLayout Container R.id.container
  // Depending on the Fragment you can change the Title
  setTitle("xyz");    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new class in your package and extend with `Fragment` says `TestFragment` and create abstract method in it

```
abstract public String getTitle();
```

than extend your every fragment with `TestFragment` and override `getTitle()` in your fragments.

```
public String getTitle(){
      return "YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME";
}


getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
                        this.setTitle(fragment.getTitle());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I have done this but problem is that List is referencing the second last fragment not the last one. Please suggest.  Like if I add the fragment B the setTitle of fragment A is being called.

Comment: Create a post delay of 100-200 using handler, than check

Comment: have you override onBackPressed() in your activity??

Comment: Yes; Is there something which is conflicting it?